# Keeping multiple classes 'open' without (String args[])

Tags: java, class, arguments, args

I have multiple classes in my Java project.

One is for keeping a track of how many books have been added to a virtual library. Every time the program works with a different class, the next time the book keeper class is called it's values are set back to default.

I feel like instantiating each class at `main(String args[])` with 
`static Example example = new Example();`
would work, followed by passing arguments for all classes through the methods.

Is there an easier way to do this.

Comment: I guess you'll have to add some code. As is the question is completely unclear to me.

Comment: @Fildor I don't want the variables to reset every time the class is re-called. So if the script stops interacting with the class keeping a track of the books, I want it to keep its position and remember the number of books the next time the script interacts with it, not reset back to 0.

Comment: Usually you'll use some sort of persistence tool for this. As Gildraths answers, you could use a Singleton to keep the BookKeeper in memory during the whole runtime. If you want the data persistent even after exiting and restarting the program, you need some additional persistence like writing to File. Alternatively you could use a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into the singleton-pattern. It makes sure that you only have one instance of an object.

```
public class BookKeeper{
private static BookKeeper instance;

private BookKeeper{
}

public synchronized static BookKeeper getInstance(){
if(instance == null){
 instance = new BookKeeper();
}
return instance;
}
```

Afterwards instead of new BookKeeper you call BookKeeper.getInstance(). This will ensure you are always having the same object (with the data in it)

Comment: Mind that this example of a lazy singleton is **not** thread-safe! And also, it is lacking a `static` at the `instance`.

Comment: @Fildor I also forgot the return instance ;) Thanks for checking!

Comment: So if I had a method inside bookKeeper, how would I call it? BookKeeper.getInstance().method(); ?

Comment: @LauchlanIrwin Yes that would work. You can also assign it to a variable like: BookKeeper keeper = BookKeeper.getInstance() and then just use keeper from there on.